# link two containers in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to connect two container such a way that frontend can connect to backend using `0.0.0.0:9999`
Here is my docker-compose

```
    version: '3.5'
    services:
      diag-front:
        container_name: diag-front
        image: util/tool-frontend-development:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "80"
        links:
          - diag-back
        networks:
          - "mycloud"
      diag-back:
        container_name: diag-back
        image: util/tool-backend-development:latest
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "9999"
        networks:
          - "mycloud"

    networks:
      mycloud:
        name: mycloud
```

On the local host I am able to reach to `0.0.0.0:9999` but not from `diag-front` container

What changes I need to make here for this communication to happen ?

Answer (score 0):

From `diag-front` container, use the docker-compose service name as the hostname. In this case, use `diag-back:9999` to resolve the container on the port you want.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Related, [see the documentation on links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links). You don't really need them here in order for these containers to resolve each other by hostname.