# Access mariadb docker container from R

Tags: r, docker, mariadb

I've set up a docker container with [photoprism](https://docs.photoprism.app/getting-started/docker-compose/), which is self-hosted replacement for Google Photos, and imported all my pictures into its database. Now I think it would be really cool to get access to the MariaDB database that the program uses. The database is in a separate docker container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
bc9832e0cac1   mariadb:10.5                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp, :::3307->3306/tcp   pictures_mariadb_1
27eb740da6bd   photoprism/photoprism:latest   "/entrypoint.sh phot…"   6 weeks ago     Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:2342->2342/tcp, :::2342->2342/tcp   pictures_photoprism_1
```

The docker-compose file contains the info to access the database:

```
      PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_DRIVER: "mysql"            # Use MariaDB (or MySQL) instead of SQLite for improved performance
      PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_SERVER: "mariadb:3306"     # MariaDB database server (hostname:port)
      PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_NAME: "photoprism"         # MariaDB database schema name
      PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_USER: "photoprism"         # MariaDB database user name
      PHOTOPRISM_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "XXXXXXXX"       # MariaDB database user password
```

An further down in the file is the docker compose part for mariadb:

```
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3307:3306 # 3306 is already in use
    security_opt:
      - seccomp:unconfined
      - apparmor:unconfined
    command: mysqld --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci --max-connections=512 --innodb-rollback-on-timeout=OFF --innodb-lock-wait-timeout=50
    volumes: # Don't remove permanent storage for index database files!
      - "~/.mariadb/database:/var/lib/mysql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: YYYYYYYY
      MYSQL_DATABASE: photoprism
      MYSQL_USER: photoprism
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXX
```

I tried to translate this into `R` code, but I have very limited experience with the underlying packages and also don't know enough about Docker. So my guess was that one of these code chunks should work (but they don't):

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
  dbname = "photoprism",
  username = "photoprism",
  password = "XXXXXXXX",
  host = "mariadb",
  port = 3307
)
#> Error: Failed to connect: Unknown MySQL server host 'mariadb' (-2)
```

```r
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  drv = RMariaDB::MariaDB(),
  dbname = "photoprism",
  username = "photoprism",
  password = "XXXXXXXX",
  host = "localhost",
  port = 3307
)
#> Error: Failed to connect: Access denied for user 'photoprism'@'localhost'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I'm trying to access the container on the same machine which is running the containers. So localhost should be correct.

Comment: Can you show your docker compose file? If you start the mariadb container with the same environment variables (`MARIADB_USER=photoprism`, `MARIADB_DATABASE=photoprism` and `MARIADB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX`) as the connection parameters the `photoprism` then the user will be created. There's a networking aspect between the two containers that also needs to be addressed.

Comment: Good point! I didn't notice there was a mariadb part at the end of the file. I updated the question.

Comment: Does your photoprism yaml have a [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012815/link-two-containers-in-docker-compose#53013032) to mariadb? if so `host = "mariadb"` and `port = 3306` and no port mapping is needed as the port isn't expose to the host.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the user "photoprism" is already logged in (?). I can log in perfectly fine by using `username = "root",   password = "XXXXXXXX",`.